# Convert string representation of dictionary to dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, casting

Is their a way to convert strings illustrating dictionaries into some dictionary in Python.

E.g. I want to convert the string:

```
s = "{1:p→q,2: ¬q,3: ¬ (¬p),4: ¬p,5:[edge(¬p,¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),edge(¬ (¬p),¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),rule('∧I')],6:[edge(¬p,p),edge(¬p∧ ¬ (¬p),p),rule('¬E')],7:[edge(p,q),edge(p→q,q),rule('→E')],8:[edge(q,q∧ ¬q),edge(¬q,q∧ ¬q),rule('∧I')],9:[edge(¬ (¬p),¬p),edge(q∧ ¬q,¬p),rule('¬E')]}"
```

into some dictionary of following form:

```
d = {1:'p→q',2: '¬q',3: '¬ (¬p)',4: '¬p',5:['edge(¬p,¬p∧ ¬ (¬p))','edge(¬ (¬p),¬p∧ ¬ (¬p))','rule("∧I")'],6:['edge(¬p,p)','edge(¬p∧ ¬ (¬p),p)','rule("¬E")'],7:['edge(p,q)','edge(p→q,q)','rule("→E")'],8:['edge(q,q∧ ¬q)','edge(¬q,q∧ ¬q)','rule("∧I")'],9:['edge(¬ (¬p),¬p)','edge(q∧ ¬q,¬p)','rule("¬E")']}
```

I've tried json.loads(s), but unfortunately it needs some string which already has the quotation marks at the values of the dictionary itself.

I hope some similar solution is possible to solve that problem.

Remark: Strings like `s` I generate from some Prolog dictionary.

Comment: Can't you get the source of the data to provide it in a more appropriate form?

Comment: that is not a string representation fo a dictionary. This is *close*, but it is not a valid python source code literal that would create a dictionary. EDIT: or do you mean, this string was created by doing something like `s = str(mydict)`?

Comment: I don't use Prolog, but it looks like it can read/write JSON. Could you export this specific data as JSON? That would make things much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it that works on your example, but would fail if things were more nested or whatever. In this case, I would rather recommend trying to get the data in a more manageable format, like JSON, rather than try to write a parser that would work in any possible case.

It's a rather crude way of parsing the string by splitting it with regex:

```
s = "{1:p→q,2: ¬q,3: ¬ (¬p),4: ¬p,5:[edge(¬p,¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),edge(¬ (¬p),¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),rule('∧I')],6:[edge(¬p,p),edge(¬p∧ ¬ (¬p),p),rule('¬E')],7:[edge(p,q),edge(p→q,q),rule('→E')],8:[edge(q,q∧ ¬q),edge(¬q,q∧ ¬q),rule('∧I')],9:[edge(¬ (¬p),¬p),edge(q∧ ¬q,¬p),rule('¬E')]}"

import re

# We split on optional ",", a number and ":" 
split = re.split(r',?(\d+):', s[1:-1])
# ['', '1', 'p→q', '2', ' ¬q', '3', ' ¬ (¬p)' ...]

# Convert the numbers to int
split[1::2] = [int(n) for n in split[1::2]]

# We create a dict with the numbers as keys
d = dict(zip(split[1::2], split[2::2]))

# The values starting with "[" need to be converted to lists
for k, v in d.items():
    if v.startswith('['):
        # We split on "edge" or "rule"
        split = re.split(',?(edge|rule)',v[1:-1])
        # and create the list, joining each separator with what follows it
        d[k] = list(''.join(parts) for parts in zip(split[1::2], split[2::2]))
        
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'p→q',
 2: ' ¬q',
 3: ' ¬ (¬p)',
 4: ' ¬p',
 5: ['edge(¬p,¬p∧ ¬ (¬p))', 'edge(¬ (¬p),¬p∧ ¬ (¬p))', "rule('∧I')"],
 6: ['edge(¬p,p)', 'edge(¬p∧ ¬ (¬p),p)', "rule('¬E')"],
 7: ['edge(p,q)', 'edge(p→q,q)', "rule('→E')"],
 8: ['edge(q,q∧ ¬q)', 'edge(¬q,q∧ ¬q)', "rule('∧I')"],
 9: ['edge(¬ (¬p),¬p)', 'edge(q∧ ¬q,¬p)', "rule('¬E')"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library I wrote, called `tocode` read the doc and example [here](https://github.com/Amir-Shamsi/tocode):

1. Install it using:

```
pip install tocode==0.1.3
```

2. Import it and use it:

```py
import tocode

# Example
s = "{this: 5, (Alex, Daniel): are good boys, (5, 4): 8.5}"
s = tocode.literal_eval(s, no_string_quotation=True)
```

Output:

```py
{'this': 5, ('Alex', 'Daniel'): 'are good boys', (5, 4): 8.5}
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'tocode' has no attribute 'literal_eval'`

Comment: yes, try 10 min later I'm fixing it

Comment: Thanks, after printing with print(s) it shows the error: invalid character '→' (U+2192) at line 1. Is their some unicode problem?

Comment: Yes it can't see the `→` as a part of the string because it thinks `→` is a command

Comment: Please note that this doesn't answer the question at all, as it doesn't demonstrate how using this specific library of yours could parse the OP's data the way he expects.

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you.

Finally, After a long time using my small brain I got the same output as you want using pure python without using any module.

```py
s = "{1:p→q,2: ¬q,3: ¬ (¬p),4: ¬p,5:[edge(¬p,¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),edge(¬ (¬p),¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),rule('∧I')],6:[edge(¬p,p),edge(¬p∧ ¬ (¬p),p),rule('¬E')],7:[edge(p,q),edge(p→q,q),rule('→E')],8:[edge(q,q∧ ¬q),edge(¬q,q∧ ¬q),rule('∧I')],9:[edge(¬ (¬p),¬p),edge(q∧ ¬q,¬p),rule('¬E')]}"

s = s[1:-1].split(':')

d = {}
def return_value(value):
    
    if value.startswith('['):
        l = value
        l = l[1:-1].split('),')
        for i in range(len(l)-1):
            l[i] = l[i]+')'
        value = l
    return value
for v in range(len(s)):
   if v != len(s)-2:
        try:
            value = s[v+1][:-2]
            value = return_value(value)
            d[int(s[v][-1])]=value
        except:
            pass

   else:
        value = s[v+1]
        value = return_value(value)
        value[0]=value[0]+value[1]
        del value[1]
        d[int(s[v][-1])]=value
print(d)
```

**Output**

```py
{1: 'p→q', 2: ' ¬q', 3: ' ¬ (¬p)', 4: ' ¬p', 5: ['edge(¬p,¬p∧ ¬ (¬p))', 'edge(¬ (¬p)', '¬p∧ ¬ (¬p))', "rule('∧I')"], 6: ['edge(¬p,p)', 'edge(¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)', 'p)', "rule('¬E')"], 7: ['edge(p,q)', 'edge(p→q,q)', "rule('→E')"], 8: ['edge(q,q∧ ¬q)', 'edge(¬q,q∧ ¬q)', "rule('∧I')"], 9: ['edge(¬ (¬p)¬p)', 'edge(q∧ ¬q,¬p)', "rule('¬E'"]}
```

Comment: it doesn't create array `"[edge(¬p,¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),edge(¬ (¬p),¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),rule('∧I')]"` and makes it string

Comment: @AmirShamsi Bro try this it works perfectly.

Comment: besides it changes numbers into strings

Comment: @AmirShamsi Check Now, I Just Edit.

Comment: yes numbers fixed but the list `[edge(¬p,¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),edge(¬ (¬p),¬p∧ ¬ (¬p)),rule('∧I')]` still will be returned as a string, not a list

Comment: @AmirShamsi Yeah Its to complicated, Try after 10 min.

Comment: @AmirShamsi Hey Bro I got it.

Comment: This is not the expected output. In the 5th value, your list contains `'edge(¬ (¬p)', '¬p∧ ¬ (¬p))',`, which should not be split on the comma in the middle of `edge(....)`.

Comment: @SharimIqbal I appreciate your try but it's still not fixed

Comment: Also, note that using  `value = s[v+1][:-2]` and `d[int(s[v][-1])]=value` will fail as soon as there are more than 9 keys, as you supposed that the numbers only can have 1 digit.

Comment: @AmirShamsi Check Now.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille your code also fail if there is more and more nested list.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I am writing this code for the given problem not for all of the his\her problems.

Comment: @SharimIqbal it's great bro, but still needs to improve, for example at the end it prints this `"rule('¬E'"]}`

Comment: @AmirShamsi Its a small problem now I edit.